# Navigation menu bar problems with alignment elements

Tags: html, css

I'm testing a navigation bar at top of the web page with a dropbox menu align at right. I have a lot of problems with space from the menu to the background of the bar and also with align icons with text.

My Code is this:

```js
function dropdownClick() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    html
    {
        position: relative; 
        min-height: 100%;
     font-family: Gotham-Light;
     
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
  
    /* Def. Navigation Bar */
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #dedee1;
    }
    
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    
    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }
    
    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link href="assets/css-styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
     <title>navigation</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <nav> 
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#page1">Page1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
                      
                      <li style="float:right" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdownClick()"><i class="material-icons">face</i>Username</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                            <a href="#settings"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>  preferències</a>
                            <a href="#preferences"><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  canviar password</a>
                            <a href="#logout"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i>  log out</a> 
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
    
         </nav>       
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The boxes of the active link doesn't align to the top of the navigation bar And the icon with the text 'username' aresn't align with each other.

Sorry but I'm beginner in the css styles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm everything looks ok. see here > https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/ftLh4m8b/

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE ANY EXPECTED OUTPUT IMAGE??

Comment: Sorry but I don't see well... How to insert an image into the question?

Comment: which part of your navbar has a problem??

Comment: The example of the @Mihai it's good but for me not. I think that the problem is with images. How to make a navigation bar with a fix measurements? With this I could put images an align text.

Comment: Yeats ago I made with <table>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `li a, .dropbtn` display to `block` instead of `inline-block` (that causes in this case an unwanted margin).

Another reason is the `i`, give that a `float: left`;

Last problem is that submenu appears outside the screen, add  a `right: 0` to it.

```js
function dropdownClick() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    html
    {
        position: relative; 
        min-height: 100%;
     font-family: Gotham-Light;
     
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
  
    /* Def. Navigation Bar */
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #dedee1;
    }
    
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    
    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }
    
    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
      right: 0;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .show {display:block;}

.dropbtn i { float: left;  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link href="assets/css-styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
     <title>navigation</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <nav> 
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#page1">Page1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
                      
                      <li style="float:right" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdownClick()"><i class="material-icons">face</i>Username</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                            <a href="#settings"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>  preferències</a>
                            <a href="#preferences"><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  canviar password</a>
                            <a href="#logout"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i>  log out</a> 
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
    
         </nav>       
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks @LinkinTED. Solved: submenu appears outside the screen, add a right: 0, Thanks!